# Why are functions like memchr bound to C implementations rather than being written in pure Rust?

Tags: c, rust

Functions like `memchr` seem quite simple but Rust projects use [bindings to the C code](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-memchr/blob/master/src/lib.rs) with only a Rust fallback, rather than implementing them in Rust. Can't `memchr` be efficiently implemented in Rust?

Comment: I'm pretty sure libc's `memchr` (at least GNU libc) is written either mostly or completely in assembly.

Comment: As you can see in the link you provided, there is a `memchr` written in Rust, but it's only used on windows, because only on windows the Rust-`memchr` is faster than the `libc`-`memchr`

Comment: Is the question specifically about C-bindings or is it about using only Rust? This would affect whether inlined assembly in Rust code is considered "Rust" or not.

Comment: It's an interesting twist on [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) — incorrectly state that something *can't* be done and watch the answers roll in!

Comment: @Shepmaster Ha :) Then perhaps my question should have been "why aren't" rather than "why can't".

Comment: You can always [edit] your question if you think that it's currently sub-par.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They can. If you look at glibc's implementation, it will look somewhat like [`fallback:memchr`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-memchr/blob/62eae0de4a5d231467b27ca6719f000c63f4edf2/src/lib.rs#L251). However, that's only part of the story. The [generic implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/memchr.c;h=ca9fd99f2105003d0b56285ff3f41ba10dad8685;hb=HEAD) is used only when there isn't a more appropriate one available.

For example, [x68-64 has a variant written in assembly](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S;h=132eacba8f88b691c35666c99f611a2a98727a13;hb=HEAD). And so do [many](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memchr.S;hb=HEAD) [other](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/i386/memchr.S;h=e8834349e6aba97b67928031c5616e5003b75507;hb=HEAD) architectures, that provide sophisticated instructions.

So to reach the same speed, Rust would have to provide something similar on instruction level, which essentially boils down to the same (or better) assembly. At that point you're just duplicating work. It's already there, no need to create everything anew.

Comment: *It's already there, no need to create everything anew.* => might be more convenient (for the user) not to have to link against libc, but otherwise I agree. DRY & all that.

Comment: I think we need the proven and tuned low level functions like this from glibc to compete. They have literally hundreds of assembly implementations for various platforms of memcpy, memchr and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Zeta. I don't have much knowledge of LLVM or C, and I assumed that this sort of low-level operation would be best implemented in LLVM, and be available to the Rust compiler.

Answer (score 8):

There is an assumption here that the *only* reason to link to a C library is for efficiency.

I am afraid that you are forgetting *convenience* here. Just because a function *could* be implemented as efficiently in Rust as in C (possibly leveraging `unsafe` code and assembly) does not mean that it is convenient to do so.

Rather than attempt to produce an optimized implementation for each and every platform under the sun, it is simply more convenient to be able to fallback to the already provided C function to start with, and then gradually tune for the platforms you care for if necessary.

Producing an implementation that is tailored specifically to the hardware/OS is a lengthy job, and if someone already poured in the effort it might make sense to just reuse its result!

Comment: I think my actual assumption was different (and also incorrect). That is, I didn't consider the fairly obvious point that the C version is actually just a binding to assembly code targeting many hardware permutations. And you are right - it isn't convenient or worthwhile to bind to that assembly, when you can re-use the C at zero cost.

Answer (score 2):

They can, but according to documentation in [Rust's GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/11946956a6352f49c6aadc1c13c39757a046e0c2/src/libstd/memchr.rs#L16-L23) this is for performance reasons:

> memchr reduces to super-optimized machine code at around an order of
>   magnitude faster than `haystack.iter().position(|&b| b == needle)`.
>   (See benchmarks.)

Since benchmarks indicate that `memchr()` from C-bindings results in a far better performance, that version is the preferred one. Trying to optimize a Rust variant further would probably result in including some assembly, so it would boil down to the same thing.

Comment: That's a bit of a cop-out: why not simply port the optimized `memchr` to Rust? There is, in theory, nothing preventing Rust from reaching C/assembly speeds (especially as it can include assembly code, on nightly at least), and BurntSushi has gone to great extent to tune his Regex library, so why not for `memchr`?

Comment: This would not be _pure_ Rust, though - and that is what the question was about.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. First of all, SIMD can be used in pure Rust (on nightly) and second of all the question only refers to C-bindings, not inline assembly so it's unclear whether the OP judges it acceptable.

Comment: That's true; I'll include an additional note in my answer.

Comment: I've asked the OP about this distinction, as far as I am concerned it should be OK; I mostly see C-bindings as an *inconvenience* (have to have the C lib available, configure cargo to link against it, etc...) so I don't consider inline assembly with the same stigma. Both are unsafe, but `unsafe` is part of Rust too :)